# Django Rest and Axios

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios, django-csrf

I am trying to post data using DRF and Axios. I have tried a couple different options so far with the same result, 403 (Forbidden). I am able to get data using axios.get but not able to post data. I am new to rest and using ajax so I apologize if it is something obvious.

## Axios call

```
return axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: "/schedules/",
                data: {
                    "emp": this.emp.emp,
                    'start_time': this.startTime,
                    "end_time": this.endTime,
                    "date": this.today,
                    "location": this.location
                },
                xsrfHeaderName: "X-CSRFToken",
                responseType: 'json'
              })
```

## Settings.py

```
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XSRF-TOKEN"
```

## Serializer

```
class SchedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = (
            'location',
            'emp',
            'date',
            'start_time',
            'end_time'
        )
```

## View

```
class SchedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Schedule.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SchedSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the setup I am using that works. There are two things, you need to make sure that your header is being sent correctly.

```
HTTP.defaults.headers.post['x-csrftoken'] = {{csrf_token}};
HTTP.post('django-url/', {"id":id,"value":resp})
```

I was able to solve this with https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers.
Make sure that your csrf_token is populating correctly, then make sure that you are allowing the proper headers to be passed to the django app in settings.py:

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
...
    'x-csrftoken',
...
}
```